# twilio voice to voice call

Tags: qt, pyqt, twilio, qnetworkaccessmanager

We are using QNetworkAccessManager and want to do person to person live call, how do we do this? Can you send a link to find more information where we can find this.

If this is not possible, which other technology can we use to control with a QT c++ application to get this done?

we are using QT 5.15.2, and are able to send text, enter a number which twilio will call with a prerecorded message, but we cannot figure out how to do real voice to voice calls yet.
Somehow we need to redirect audio from the pc (microphone and earpiece) to the twilio voice call while we are able to record this call.

Thank you

Comment: Sorry but StackOverflow is not a tutorial website, and we expect a minimum research effort so that we can answer to questions about specific and detailed topics. Generic "I don't know how to do it" questions are normally considered off topic. Please take your time to follow the [tour], read [ask] and review the [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).